# IMAGES Sometimes 0 KB And Black IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I save my images on

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.data valueForKey:@"message"]];
```

But sometimes images loaded properly by using Haneke

```
  NSLog(@"%@",path);
    [self.contentImage hnk_setImageFromFile:path placeholder:nil success:^(UIImage *image) {

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
```

}

[image]
And Images Becomes black sometimes...I guess the path not correct path..What did u say?

**EDIT:OH I found that the image lenght is bigger than 0 68900 etc.But the images are black...!!!So there is no wrong with path**

Comment: Are you sure that `path` is a valid path?

Comment: I think you should check the property opaque for this and then try.